# Returning none instead of my string

Tags: python

Trying to get it to loop 5 times for the zipcode, making 5 different strings of ":::||" things. Its currently printing as   | None 6 | which none stands for the suppose to be 5 different statements (":::||") any ideas?

```
zipcode=input("What is your 5 digit zipcode?") #gives the zipcode
#x,z,c,d,e=zipcode.split()  #splits the zipcode into 5 sections   IGNORE

def correctiondigit(zipcode):     #LAST BLOCK OF 6 BLOCK BARCODE
    zipcode.split()
    total=     int(zipcode[0])+int(zipcode[1])+int(zipcode[2])+int(zipcode[3])+int(zipcode[4])
    if total % 10!=0:
        total=10-total%10
    return total

#return(correctiondigit(zipcode))            IGNORE

def barcode(a):
    if a==0:
        return("||:::")
    elif a==1:
        return(":::||")
    elif a==2:
        return("::|:|")
    elif a==3:
        return("::||:")
    elif a==4:
        return(":|::|")
    elif a==5:
        return(":|:|:")
    elif a==6:
        return(":||::")
    elif a==7:
        return("|:::|")
    elif a==8:
        return("|::|:")
    elif a==9:
       return("|:|::")


def makebar(x):
    zipcode.split()
    for i in zipcode:
        barcode(x)

print("|",makebar(zipcode),correctiondigit(zipcode),"|") #prints barcode in not barcode form...
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even work as written. `zipcode.split()` probably doesn't do what you think it does. If you do a `.split` method on a string like `'12345'` it will be a list of a single item like `["12345"]` And if you try to iterate over that, you only iterate over one item, not the characters in the string. This is why `barcode` is returning `None` because what you're passing in never equals anything there.

Comment: Sorry Im really new to python, I was sick during the class explaining split, but i was told it worked that way. How would i get it to split the inputted 5 digits the take each digit through my function to print the final 5 barcode combination

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several errors. The first one I saw was in `makebar`, with `zipcode.split()` that doesn't save the result anywhere. `for i in zipcode:` is therefore iterating over each character in the zip code rather than each "word." There aren't even any words in a zip code; just a string with no whitespace, so `split()` won't accomplish anything. Secondly, you are iterating over `zipcode` and not using the iterated values, sending the entire passed `x` (which is a reference to the global variable `zipcode`) each time through the loop. Next, you have no way of accumulating the results of those `barcode` calls. Finally, `makebar` has no `return` statement, so it implicitly returns `None`.

```
def makebar(x):
    return ''.join(map(barcode, x))
```

And that's only in `makebar`. Your code may have additional errors that produce tracebacks or other unwanted results. You'll have to look over your code very carefully and review any instructional materials you've been working with.

Comment: zipcode is the inputted 5 digits from the user, I need the input "zipcode" (55555) to be put through the function 5 times...

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, in your func definition: 
   `def makebar(x):
       zipcode.split()
       for i in zipcode:
           barcode(x)`
   zipcode.split()  just return a list, didn't change zipcode itself.
   And `for i in zip code:` , each i is a str(a single char), not int you want.
2. In `def barcode(a):`
   Beacause you pass a str, so it can't fit any conditions you set.
    Eventually you got None(automatically return value).
3. I suggest you change `barcode(x)` into `yield barcode(int(i))` and the last statement into `print("|",*makebar(zipcode),correctiondigit(zipcode),"|")` (notice the * notation)

Comment: so do i need to change I in the     for i in zipcode:     ?

Comment: I have changed my answer. And I supposed you want to get a series of code like  | ||::: ::|:| ::||: :|::| :|:|: 6 |  . You should focus on some detailed like return value and type of args.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is close to what you are trying to achieve.
I'm unsure as to the nature of your check digit calculation but I assume that it should have a method of saying that it is incorrect, I have used "X".

```
zipcode=input("What is your 5 digit zipcode?") #gives the zipcode
try:
    num = int(zipcode)
except:
    print("Invalid Zipcode - requires numeric input only")  #Test for numeric input
    quit()
if len(zipcode) != 5:                                       # test input length
    print("Invalid Zipcode - requires 5 numerics")
    quit()

def correctiondigit(zipcode):     #LAST BLOCK OF 6 BLOCK BARCODE
    total = sum(int(i) for i in zipcode)                    #Calculate total
    if total % 10!=0:
        total=10-total%10
    else:
        total = "X"                                         #Check digit incorrect
    return total

def barcode(a):
    if a==0:
        return("||:::")
    elif a==1:
        return(":::||")
    elif a==2:
        return("::|:|")
    elif a==3:
        return("::||:")
    elif a==4:
        return(":|::|")
    elif a==5:
        return(":|:|:")
    elif a==6:
        return(":||::")
    elif a==7:
        return("|:::|")
    elif a==8:
        return("|::|:")
    elif a==9:
       return("|:|::")


def makebar(x):                                             #Build barcode representation
    bar=[]                                                  #Using a list
    for i in zipcode:
        bar.append(barcode(int(i)))
    return bar

print("|",makebar(zipcode),correctiondigit(zipcode),"|")
```

Output:

```
What is your 5 digit zipcode?12345
| [':::||', '::|:|', '::||:', ':|::|', ':|:|:'] 5 |
What is your 5 digit zipcode?13131
| [':::||', '::||:', ':::||', '::||:', ':::||'] 1 |
What is your 5 digit zipcode?22222
| ['::|:|', '::|:|', '::|:|', '::|:|', '::|:|'] X |
```